# What is this cable painted into wall going up staircase?

Tags: wiring, painting, trim

Have a weird wire, we think it's copper, that goes up my staircase and for most of it fits inside the moulding. But there is a part that is slacking.

Not sure if I should cut the wire where it's slacking or paint over it again. Here is a pic[image: wire]

Comment: We can guess what it is with some confidence, but that doesn't tell you what to do with it (and it's still a guess). You'll need to investigate the ends of the thing and make your own call on whether to remove it.

Answer (score 7):

That is a cloth covered cable and most likely live.
There is nothing weird about it it is very common in older homes pre 1960’s the cable was just painted over many times. In the past electrical code was not well enforced so exposed electrical may be more common in some locations.

Never cut a wire you do not know what it is! This wire could have 240v and when cutting that live the arc and molten metal can injure you and start a fire.

If you investigate and find out this is still needed there are covers like wiremold brand to protect live wires. Just make sure to verify it is not in use and it’s not live prior to cutting.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, looks like electrical wire to me.

It looks like the outer sheathing was damaged so I would definitely wrap it in a few layers of electrical tape.

Invest in a handy-dandy [Non-Contact Voltage Tester Pen](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Klein-Tools-Non-Contact-Voltage-Tester-Pen-50-to-1000V-AC-NCVT1PR/317460355). For $20 it will let you avoid a lot of headache and can help keep you out of the hospital or cemetery.

Based on the picture, I don't see any exposed copper/aluminum so if you want a quick fix then hot glue it back into place so that it does not sag.

Alternatively, you could also grab a pack of NM cable staples and tack it into place but it could be an eyesore.

Answer (score -6):

I'd pull it all out. It looks like old telephone wire or a coax for tv. I've seen it ran like that before because someone wanted a phone line upstairs/downstairs or maybe an office back in the dial up days.

I've also seen plenty of "cable tv guys" run coax through homes like that. You might have a tv somewhere that needs that wire intact. Still though, if you cut it out and the upstairs tv cuts off then call the cable company to come run it correctly.

Edit: No matter the type of wire. It should come out. It would be removed immediately if it were my home, especially if it was damaged. You should not paint over it. If it is electrical wire (which I don't think it is) then it should be removed asap by an electrician if you prefer.

Comment: It is definitely not coax, you can clearly see the twist of internal wires even externally. Also not telephone, as it is too thick and in the cut area you can see the braid of a sheathing material which is not typical of phone cable.

Comment: @Andrew You can also clearly see the hatching of the cloth insulation, plus the gauge of the twisted conductors is way fatter than you'd see in a communications cable (in a residence, anyway. :) ). My money is on that being a 12/3 or 14/3 mains electrical cable.  Don't just cut and pull that without testing to see what it is carrying.

Comment: @ChrisO You could be right, and given the damage, it needs to be removed as soon as possible.

Comment: @chris o I agree and communications cable of this era was usually 300 ohm flat cable .

Comment: Wow closed? This site is getting ridiculous there is a question asked a pic and it is obvious to anyone that has been in the field for any length of time

Comment: @EdBeal, no one can answer with confidence what that wire does _now_, nor should we decide what the OP does with it. That's my primary issue with the question. It requires investigation and common sense on site, not the opinion of some yahoos on the internet.

Comment: The question wasn't closed based on this answer. That's an odd conclusion. I explained my vote.

Comment: @isherwood I believe I did 100% answer the question and it was fairly simple. Now with it closed others can not learn and the op may not also because it was closed. And I felt it was good enough for an up vote as someone else did because it is fairly common in older homes.

Comment: @EdBeal you didn't answer it correctly. It is not common to have electrical wire ran that way even in older houses. They don't make covers for electrical wire like that inside someone's home either. Someone else said wrap it electrical tape (lol) then what? paint over it? I'm sorry but that is not home improvement. The correct answer is it has to come out. Simple. I still don't think it is electrical wire either. Honestly your idea of covering and leaving a live wire like that in someone's home is much more dangerous than my suggestion of removing it

Comment: @andrew I have remodeled/redecorated or totally rewired hundreds of old homes and yes there is a way to protect the surface mounted cable and one way is using wiremold 700?  the last I ordered was Legrand  don’t remember the series on that at all, but like WM it is a listed metallic raceway and yes you can run NM in a listed raceway, let’s compare licenses if you doubt me or look it up as you must not be a professional, I will explain that NM is a type of cable that may have a cloth or plastic covering today’s residential wiring is primarily NMB and it can be surface mounted by code NFPA70 fyi

Comment: Note I had not down voted before but now have even though you don’t go negative so it cost me and not you because there is no score below zero, sorry but a bad answer is just that and others agree with my answer and agree yours is not good. Gain some points by removing a down voted answer, I can’t remember what it’s called but I did it once, but if you look at my rep you can see I don’t care I regularly get hammered but am one of the very few pro’s and am actually still active as a supervising general journeyman in the state of oregon,

Comment: @edbeal I knew you'd mention wiremold and that would just be negligent in a home. What if they had children? wiremold 700 isn't for that. Maybe some sort of conduit but still not up to safety standards. Never in 200 years of building has it been a practice to run electrical wire on a stair skirt board. Yes, you see metallic raceway in commercial construction.

Comment: @andrew give it up electrical code is only a little over 120 years old and the cloth wrapped is only about 80 as a professional I have used wiremold along the base boards of Victorian homes in both Oregon and California . It is a listed metallic and totally code compliant wireway that can be used to protect wiring.